# problem with cross-references to equations in Elsevier template

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, cross-referencing, amsmath

This is the first time I ask a question. I really appreciate if anybody can help.

I have been working with the `elsarticle` document class.  unfortunately I have problem with the `hyperref` and the `fleqn` environment: Cross-references to equations are empty, i.e., they don't show equation numbers. How to fix this?

```
\documentclass[3p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage {natbib}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[maxfloats=30,morefloats=12]{morefloats}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[sright]{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb} %for z integer set presentation
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath} % for breaking long equation
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{fleqn}
        \begin{equation}\label{e:hatT}
            \begin{aligned}
                &\hat{T}_l=\hat{A}T_c+\hat{B}
            \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
    \end{fleqn}
    
    \begin{fleqn}
        \begin{equation}\label{f:eqialflow}
            \begin{aligned}
                &G_{eq}[(\hat{A}-1)T_c+\hat{B}]=\hat{C}T_c+\hat{D}\\
                &E=mc^2
            \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
    \end{fleqn}
    The TEC cold temperature ($T_c$) is determined by  Eq. (\ref{f:eqialflow}). Substituting  $T_c$ in Eq. (\ref{e:hatT})
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: Thank you. sure

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `fleqn` option to [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and remove the `\mathindent` (`\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}`). This allows you to avoid using the `fleqn` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[3p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}% for breaking long equation

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{e:hatT}
  \hat{T}_l = \hat{A} T_c + \hat{B}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{f:eqialflow}
  \begin{aligned}
    &G_{eq}[(\hat{A} - 1) T_c + \hat{B}] = \hat{C} T_c + \hat{D} \\
    &E = mc^2
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The TEC cold temperature~($T_c$) is determined by Eq.~(\ref{f:eqialflow}).
Substituting~$T_c$ in Eq.~(\ref{e:hatT}).
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: wow! thank you very much. I dont think I could solve my problem so soon. Its kind of you and Don Hosek.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and diagnose your problem from a partial text screenshot.

**Item 1**: You put the `\label` command for your equation outside the `equation` environment. If you do that, it will not refer to the equation but will refer to the last section number (which in this case is probably 2.2). You should have something like this:

```
\begin{equation}
 ... - m'^{2}\theta_{l} = 
   \frac{Q_{xz}{k}
\label{myequation}
\end{equation}
```

The `\label` command can go anywhere in the `equation` environment, but if you're consistent (and you keep it on a line by itself), you'll find your life is much easier.

**Item 2**. It looks like you've written something like this:

```
Eq. \eqref{myequation}
```

You will notice that the spacing between “Eq.” and the equation number is much too big. This is because LaTeX is incorrectly assuming that “Eq.” is the end of a sentence and inserts end of sentence spacing.¹ Instead, you should write

```
Eq.~\eqref{myequation}
```

which will force regular word spacing and as an added bonus keep there from being a line brek between “Eq.” and “(19).”

Or better still, loading `cleveref`³ will allow you to just write

```
\Cref{myequation}
```

and get the `Eq.~` automatically prefixed to the referene.

---

1. That TeX/LaTeX do this at all is its own typographic crime, but I'll let this pass. I think the primary reason why TeX does this is because Knuth came up with a clever algorithm that he wanted to implement, much like the `\t` accent which has close to zero practical use.²
2. I've spent long periods of time trying to track down any use case for this outside of phonetic pronunciation typesetting and that use case for TeX is questionable insofar as other characters also necessary for that are absent from the original Computer Modern fonts.
3. Note that there's only one `r` in `cleveref`. I think this was perhaps a bit too clever, so to speak.

Comment: Thank you very much for your perfect answer, I was really surprised

Comment: But unfortunately I got new error

Comment: It appears to be some odd interaction with the `fleqn` environment. Unless you only want some equations flush left, it's better to just specify `fleqn` as an option on your document class.

Comment: Interesting.   I wish you all the best